# How to delete file after download with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to delete a file immediately after download, how do I do it? I've tried to subclass `FilePathResult` and override the `WriteFile` method where I delete file after

```
HttpResponseBase.TransmitFile
```

is called, but this hangs the application.

Can I safely delete a file after user downloads it?

Comment: The solution should go in an 'answer', not in the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could create a custom actionfilter for the action with an OnActionExecuted Method that would then remove the file after the action was completed, something like

```
public class DeleteFileAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute 
{ 
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext) 
    { 
        // Delete file 
    } 
}
```

then your action has

```
[DeleteFileAttribute]
public FileContentResult GetFile(int id)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: The download hangs and never finishes, ideas?

Comment: Of course, I wasnt thinking, you're deleting the file before the download is complete. Could you not delete the previously generated file before each request for a new result, thats what I've done in a similar sounding situation.

Comment: It adds unnecessary complexity, I should store downloaded files in DB then since there is no way to keep the previos file known to subsequent.

Comment: This idea is workable, however it doesn't work unless the response is flushed as mentioned in Trax72's answer below.

Comment: For me: onActionExecuteddid did not work correctly - but 'OnResultExecuted' worked (see alternative answers below).

Answer (score 90):

You can return just regular `FileStreamResult` which is opened with `FileOptions.DeleteOnClose`. File stream will be disposed with result by asp.net. This answer dosen't require usage of low level response methods which may backfire in certain situations. Also no extra work will be done like loading file to memory as whole.

```
var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None, 4096, FileOptions.DeleteOnClose);
return File(
    fileStream: fs,
    contentType: System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet,
    fileDownloadName: "File.abc");
```

This answer is based on answer by Alan West and comment by Thariq Nugrohotomo.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Simplest solution by far, in my opinion.

Comment: I highly recommend this answer above the others. (And remember to upvote Thariq Nugrohotomo's comment on this answer as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14763098/170309 )

Comment: This answer worked best for me as I cannot load the file into memory due to it's size and no extra action attributes or delegates required.

Comment: Should definitely be the accepted answer.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Method worked perfectly for me. Love it's elegance!

Answer (score 37):

Read in the bytes of the file, delete it, call the base controller's File action.

```
public class MyBaseController : Controller
{
    protected FileContentResult TemporaryFile(string fileName, string contentType, string fileDownloadName)
    {
        var bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
        System.IO.File.Delete(fileName);
        return File(bytes, contentType, fileDownloadName);
    }
}
```

BTW, you may refrain from this method if you're dealing with very large files, and you're concerned about the memory consumption.

Comment: are you sure this is a valid answer for this question?

Comment: +1 I like this one better then the accepted answer. There is no attribute or request flushing required, and the code is obvious: Read the filebytes into memory, delete the phisical file and return the bytes from memory to the user. Thanks!

Comment: This solution does not scale, for large files or lots of users.  The memory consumption will grow exponentially as users and/or file size grows.

Comment: for better scalability, you can switch into FileStreamResult, and the stream itself should be opened with `FileOptions.DeleteOnClose`. This way after you pass the stream and ASP done with the stream, the stream will be closed and file automatically deleted. (except on system crash duh)

Answer (score 35):

Create file and save it.

Response.Flush() sends all data to client.

Then you can delete temporary file.

This works for me:

```
FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath(tmpFile));

//create file, and save it
//...

string attachment = string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileName);
Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
Response.ContentType = fileType;
Response.WriteFile(newFile.FullName);
Response.Flush();
newFile.Delete();
Response.End();
```

Comment: Will it also work for big files ( greater than 512 Mb) ?

Answer (score 23):

Above answers helped me, this is what I ended up with:

```
public class DeleteFileAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
  public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
  {
     filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Flush();
     var filePathResult = filterContext.Result as FilePathResult;
     if (filePathResult != null)
     {
        System.IO.File.Delete(filePathResult.FileName);
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I performed same action in WebAPI. I needed to delete file just after it downloaded form server.
We can create custom response message class. It takes file path as parameter and delete it once its transmitted.

```
 public class FileHttpResponseMessage : HttpResponseMessage
    {
        private readonly string filePath;

        public FileHttpResponseMessage(string filePath)
        {
            this.filePath = filePath;
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            base.Dispose(disposing);
            File.Delete(filePath);
        }
    }
```

Use this class as below code and it will delete your file once it will be written on response stream.

```
var response = new FileHttpResponseMessage(filePath);
            response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
            response.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
                FileName = "MyReport.pdf"
            };
            return response;
```

Comment: It is not necessary to call `Content.Dispose()` - it is called within `base.Dispose(diposing)` call.

Answer (score 5):

overriding the OnResultExecuted method is probably the correct solution.. This method runs after the response is written.

```
public class DeleteFileAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute 
{ 
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext) 
    { 
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Flush();
        // Delete file 
    } 
}
```

Action code:

```
[DeleteFileAttribute]
public FileContentResult GetFile(int id)
{
   //your action code
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is updated answer based on elegant solution by @biesiad for ASP.NET MVC ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/4488411/1726296)

Basically it returns EmptyResult after response is sent.

```
public ActionResult GetFile()
{
    string theFilename = "<Full path your file name>"; //Your actual file name
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=<file name to be shown as download>"); //optional if you want forced download
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"; //Appropriate content type based of file type
        Response.WriteFile(theFilename); //Write file to response
        Response.Flush(); //Flush contents
        Response.End(); //Complete the response
        System.IO.File.Delete(theFilename); //Delete your local file

        return new EmptyResult(); //return empty action result
}
```

Comment: i used this solution, but i need to delete file before response.end, because after is not reachable

Answer (score 2):

Try This. This will work properly.

```
public class DeleteFileAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
  public override void OnResultExecuted( ResultExecutedContext filterContext )
  {
    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Flush();
    string filePath = ( filterContext.Result as FilePathResult ).FileName;
    File.Delete( filePath );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I preferred a solution which returned an `HttpResponseMessage`. I liked the simplicity of Risord's answer, so I created a stream in the same manner. Then, instead of returning a `File`, I set the `HttpResponseMessage.Content` property to a `StreamContent` object.

```
var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None, 4096, FileOptions.DeleteOnClose);
return new HttpResponseMessage()
{
    Content = new StreamContent(fs)
};
```

Answer (score 1):

My used pattern.

1)Create file.

2)Delete old created file, FileInfo.CreationTime < DateTime.Now.AddHour(-1)

3)User downloaded.

How about this idea?

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION:

One should either subclass the FileResult or create a custom action filter, but the tricky part is to flush the response before trying to delete the file.

Answer (score -1):

I have posted this solution in https://stackoverflow.com/a/43561635/1726296

```
public ActionResult GetFile()
    {
            string theFilename = "<Full path your file name>"; //Your actual file name
            Response.Clear();
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=<file name to be shown as download>"); //optional if you want forced download
            Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"; //Appropriate content type based of file type
            Response.WriteFile(theFilename); //Write file to response
            Response.Flush(); //Flush contents
            Response.End(); //Complete the response
            System.IO.File.Delete(theFilename); //Delete your local file

            return new EmptyResult(); //return empty action result
    }
```